# Return Max ID SQL

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with several rows as mentioned below having same account id :

```
id  account_id  id_intern    Name   Active   mobile_no    landline_no     email

1    0011abs      66654         A     yes     098937888    098937888     a@gmail.com  
2    0011abs      66655         B     yes     098937666    098937666     b@gmail.com 
3    0011abs      66656         C     no      098937777    098937777     c@gmail.com 
4    0011abs      66657         D     yes                  098937666     d@gmail.com 
5    0011abs      66658         E     yes     098937111                  e@gmail.com 
6    0011abs      66659         F     yes     098937111    098937665
```

I am searching for script that can return me just one line for all the common account_id present in the table with the following condition:

> For an account_id  with several id_intern:
> consider those lines with the status active 'yes',
> then those lines with entered mobile_no (not empty), 
> then those lines with entered landline_no (not empty), 
> then those lines with entered email (not empty), 
> then if still we have several lines (in this case for users with name A and B)
> then we will consider the line with max id_intern.

Expected Result :

```
id   account_id  id_intern    Name   active     mobile_no     landline_no   email
2    0011abs      66655         B     yes       098937666    098937666     b@gmail.com
```

I tried the script but i am unable to fulfil these conditions :(

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What if a given `account_id` has just one row, where `active` has value `'no'`, do you want to return it or not? And what if there is just one row, with `active = 'yes'` and a `null` value in `mobile_no`?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. I removed the conflicting tags, pleas tag only the one database you are running.

Comment: if a given account_id has just one row  where active has value 'no', then no need to return that line.
if there is just one row, with active = 'yes' and a null value in mobile_no or any other conditions, then return just that line as first condition is it has to be active.

Answer (score 2):

Use `row_number()` window function:

```
select id, account_id, id_intern, Name, Active, mobile_no, landline_no, email
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by account_id order by id_intern desc) rn
  from tablename
  where Active = 'yes' 
    and mobile_no is not null and landline_no is not null and email is not null
) t    
where rn = 1
```

If you want 1 row for each `account_id` even if not all the conditions are satisfied, the you must use a conditional `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select id, account_id, id_intern, Name, Active, mobile_no, landline_no, email
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (
      partition by account_id 
      order by
        case when Active = 'yes' then 1 else 2 end,
        case when mobile_no is not null then 1 else 2 end,
        case when landline_no is not null then 1 else 2 end,
        case when email is not null then 1 else 2 end,
        id_intern desc
    ) rn
  from tablename
) t    
where rn = 1
```